# Get values from wpf window resx file using vb.net

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How can i access the values found in the .resx file of a WPF window using vb.net, i mean not from xaml.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but i found the answer

the answer will be

```
        Dim rm As System.Resources.ResourceManager = 
                New System.Resources.ResourceManager("your class name", 
                                      Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
```

then, you can get the resource by its name as:

```
        rm.GetString("resource value name")
```